# Como puedo desactivar el Auto Scroll cuando llega una imagen nueva de firebase? (si estoy haciendo Scroll y llega una imagen nueva me manda al inicio)

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, scroll

Este es mi Adapdador

```
public class Myadaptador extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<Myadaptador.ViewHolder> {


    private static Bitmap bitmap_transfer;

    public static Bitmap getBitmap_transfer() {
        return bitmap_transfer;
    }

    public static void setBitmap_transfer(Bitmap bitmap_transfer_param) {
        bitmap_transfer = bitmap_transfer_param;
    }


    private Context context;

    private List<Upload> subidas;


    Activity activity = (Activity) context;


    public Myadaptador(Context context, List<Upload> subidas) {

        this.subidas = subidas;
        this.context = context;


    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_images, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        Upload upload = subidas.get(position);


        holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());

        //Picasso.get().load(upload.getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(upload.getImageUrl())
                .into(holder.imageView);


    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return subidas.size();
}

 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

     public TextView textViewName;
     public ImageView imageView;
     public Button compartir;


     public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
         super(itemView);

         compartir = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.compartir);
         textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
         imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);



         imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {


                 imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                 setBitmap_transfer(imageView.getDrawingCache());


               //  String fullname = textViewName.getText().toString();

                 Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Touchedimagen.class);
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

               //  intent.putExtra("fullname", fullname);

                 context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);


                 //Mostrar una transicion(ANIMACION) al cambiar de actividad
                 ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.scale_down);


             }
         });


     }

    }
 }
```

Esta es la Activity.java

```
 public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

//recyclerview object
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

//adapter object
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

//database reference
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

//progress dialog
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//list to hold all the uploaded images
private List<Upload>  subidas;



AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrarmemes);


    //Ocultar ActionBar
    getSupportActionBar().hide();



    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    subidas = new ArrayList<>();


    //Mostrar Progress Dialog mientras  fetching images

    progressDialog.setMessage("Espera...");
    progressDialog.show();


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constantes.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

    //adding an event listener to fetch values
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {


            //dismissing the progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //iterating through all the values in database

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);


                // Hacer que las imagenes nuevas se vean primero

                subidas.add(0,upload);



            }

            //Creando el  adapter
            adapter = new Myadaptador(Activity.this, subidas);



            //agregando adapter A recyclerview

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });



}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás creando un nuevo adapter cada que recibes datos, por lo que el recycler se vuelve a dibujar desde el item 0, lo que debes hacer es actualizar los datos del adapter.

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

//recyclerview object
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

//adapter object
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

//database reference
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

//progress dialog
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//list to hold all the uploaded images
private List<Upload>  subidas;



AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrarmemes);


    //Ocultar ActionBar
    getSupportActionBar().hide();



    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    subidas = new ArrayList<>();
    //No hay pproblema si el adapter se inicializa con una lista vacía
    adapter = new Myadaptador(this, subidas);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Mostrar Progress Dialog mientras  fetching images

    progressDialog.setMessage("Espera...");
    progressDialog.show();


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constantes.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

    //adding an event listener to fetch values
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {


            //dismissing the progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //iterating through all the values in database

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);


                // Hacer que las imagenes nuevas se vean primero

                subidas.add(0,upload);



            }
            
            //El adapter mantiene una referencia a tu lista "subidas", por lo que sólo debes indicar que el contenido de la lista se actualizó
            adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0,snapshot.getChildrenCount());

            
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
   }
}
```

Comment: Brother funciono, gracias por ayudarme llevaba semanas sin encontrar la solucion te lo agradesco mucho amigo, saludos de desde Republica Dominicana.  

Comment: de nada, saludos desde México

Comment: Bro ya que sabes cómo funciona mi codigo ¿Podrías decirme cómo implentar lo que está adjunto en la imagen, para cuando cuando cargue una imagen nueva?

@danms07

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs8Cw.jpg)